# eclipse shows exclaimation mark beside my project

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse exclamation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040914/eclipse-exclamation-mark)

eclipse shows an exclaimation mark beside my project and all the classes of that project shows no error messages. I cleaned the project and restarted again and the exclaimation mark still there.

problems tab output:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type 
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\workspaceQR 
\QRTest\bin\qrtest.jar' QR01        Build path  Build Path Problem
SupplementalInfoRetriever cannot be resolved    CaptureActivity.java    /QRTest 
/src/com/google/zxing/client/android    line 496    Java Problem
ShareActivity cannot be resolved to a type  CaptureActivity.java    /QRTest/src/com
/google/zxing/client/android    line 299    Java Problem
ResultHandlerFactory cannot be resolved CaptureActivity.java    /QRTest/src/com 
/google/zxing/client/android    line 359    Java Problem
ResultHandler cannot be resolved to a variable  CaptureActivity.java    /QRTest
/src/com/google/zxing/client/android    line 503    Java Problem
ResultHandler cannot be resolved to a type  CaptureActivity.java    /QRTest/src/com  
/google/zxing/client/android    line 359    Java Problem
ResultHandler cannot be resolved to a type  CaptureActivity.java    /QRTest/src/com
/google/zxing/client/android    line 438    Java Problem
ResultHandler cannot be resolved to a type  CaptureActivity.java    /QRTest/src/com  
/google/zxing/client/android    line 521    Java Problem
ResultButtonListener cannot be resolved to a type   CaptureActivity.java    /QRTest  
/src/com/google/zxing/client/android    line 508    Java Problem
```

and i dont have any class named QRTest but i have QR01, therefore i renamed QR01 to QRTest
but the problem still there.

any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: You must have missed some of your referenced libraries!

Rt Clk on your project folder in explorer -> Properties -> Java Build Path

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding project.also check library references if first one doesn't fix the problem.in few of my case,restarting eclipse also worked!

Comment: Check what the problem is in the "Problems" tab. If you cannot see this tab, show it using Window->Show View->Problems

Comment: Show your workspace screenshot with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when one of the project dependencies is missing. Please check the Java Build Path to see if everything looks correct. You can also take a look to the "Problems" view.