# What does the red exclamation point icon in Eclipse mean? (Icon is on right, not left)

Tags: eclipse, icons, maven-plugin

What does the red exclamation point icon in Eclipse mean? There are lots of different search results on the Internet about "red exclamation point icons" and "red exclamation mark decorators" and "red bang icons", including many on this site but the one I have on my project is on the right and not the left which everyone seems to be talking about which I think are related to build path errors. So, to be clear, this is the one I mean:

screenshot of red exclamation point icon

[image]

It appears as a decorator on projects in the Package Explorer view. The project is a Maven project using GWT. I was trying to change the pom file and did a maven install and then the icons showed up. I undid all the changes and then tried to do a clean / install and they don't seem to go away now. The problems tab is empty and I can run the project so I don't think there are any build path errors.

Comment: I think each plugin can add its red bang... so maybe you could restrict a little your question to your specific context (seems to be related to maven I guess)

Comment: is there anything in the "problems" tab?

Comment: No. Just warnings. No problems. And the applications runs fine.

Comment: have you run pmd, checkstyle, findbugs, etc?

Comment: Not for this project. Another thing I should mention is that the decorators are not on the code. They are in the folders that are generated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the reason for a red exclamation mark next to my project in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040914/what-is-the-reason-for-a-red-exclamation-mark-next-to-my-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The exclamation is on the other side of the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means there are build path problems on the project. See [What do the icons in Eclipse mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561336/what-do-the-icons-in-eclipse-mean) for details about the various icons (and icon decorators) in Eclipse.