# eclipse not showing all files in project imported from git

Tags: eclipse, github

when i am trying  to import a project from git to local eclipse, i am getting

the red exclamatory mark on project.

under working directory all files are there, but these things not showing in

eclipse project on left side. 
project folder contains only jars and pom. please find the screen shot for

reference

kindly help us on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

my mistake i was looking under package explorer instead project explorer and i have deleted the project and imported it again now it shows all the directories under my project

thanks vonC for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

A red exclamation mark should means a problem with the Build Path.
As the OP mentions, this is for the **Project Explorer**.
(and the question does not show it, but it is the **package explorer**).

Check your "[**Problems View**](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cprbview.htm?cp=0_2_4_5)" in order to see what, in the `.classpath` or `.project`, is wrong with that imported project.
See a concrete example [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10655149/6309).

Comment: there is nothing related to "tr2Web" in Problems view. (tr2Web is the project showing exclamation mark and missing files)

Comment: @user3652237 There should be, at least regarding its pom.xml